# Not sure that I have Contribution Tracker configured correctly

Tags: civicontribute, drupal

Drupal 7.37, CiviCRM 4.4.15

Principles outlined in this **[page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Update+custom+fields+in+contributions+and+events+by+passing+variables+in+a+URL)** to embed a variable in the URL that gets stored in a hidden field on the contribution page.

Do I need to make the custom fields required or read-only? I made them searchable.  For each contribution I am getting a row inserted into the database table "civicrm_value_campaign_1", but the three fields are all blank.

URL: www.domain.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=8&custom_1=sponsorship&custom_2=15&custom_3=child&amount=35.00

```
<?php

function pptsponsorship_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form)
{
// enable tracking feature
if (($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' ||
        $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm' ||
        $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou') &&
    $form->getVar('_id') == 8 ) { // use  CONTRIBUTION PAGE ID here

    // use the custom field ID and custom field label here
    $trackingFields = array('custom_1' => 'Campaign',
        'custom_2' => 'Appeal',
        'custom_3' => 'Fund');
    $form->assign('trackingFields', $trackingFields);

    if ($_GET['amount']) {
        $defaults['price_3'] = $_GET['amount']; //set the other value
        $defaults['frequency_interval'] = 1;
    }
    $form->setDefaults($defaults);
}
}
```

changed the code to the following:

function pptsponsorship_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form)
{
    // enable tracking feature
    if (($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' ||
            $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm' ||
            $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou') &&
        $form->getVar('_id') == 8 ) { // use  CONTRIBUTION PAGE ID here

```
    if (!$_GET['custom_1']) {
        require_once 'CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php';
        $defaults = CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::extractGetParams( $this, "'Contact', 'Individual', 'Contribution'" );
    } else {
        $defaults['custom_1'] = $_GET['custom_1'];
        $defaults['custom_2'] = $_GET['custom_2'];
        $defaults['custom_3'] = $_GET['custom_3'];
    }

    // use the custom field ID and custom field label here
    $trackingFields = array('custom_1' => 'Campaign:Campaign',
        'custom_2' => 'Campaign:Appeal',
        'custom_3' => 'Campaign:Fund');
    $form->assign('trackingFields', $trackingFields);

    if ($_GET['amount']) {
        $defaults['price_3'] = $_GET['amount'];
        $defaults['frequency_interval'] = 1;
    }
    $form->setDefaults($defaults);
}
```

}

It is now working.

Comment: How are you populating your hidden fields?  Are you using a jQuery snippet like the one linked to from the page you mentioned?  If so, please update your question with that code.  Also, this may not be ready in time for you, but some of what you want is coming to core: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36091.0

Comment: Missed that small step at the beginning.  Thank you

Comment: Glad that helped.  I'm going to leave that as an answer, so as not to leave a question in the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not using the jQuery snippet mentioned [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Update+custom+fields+in+contributions+and+events+by+passing+variables+in+a+URL) to populate your hidden values.

Also, there's a Google Summer of Code 2015 project that will hopefully make this question obsolete: Also, this may not be ready in time for you, but some of what you want is coming to core: forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36091.0